# Customizing bootstrap navbar color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm following Ruby on Rails tutorial and trying to customize color of navbar. My header partial is

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container", id="container">
      <%= link_to "Dog Park", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I copied to my custom.css.scss from bootstrap 3 sass source files

```
//navbar
$navbar-inverse-bg: #6dbcdb;
$navbar-inverse-border: #6dbcdb;

// Inverse navbar

.navbar-inverse {
background-color: $navbar-inverse-bg;
border-color: $navbar-inverse-border;
}
```

and nothing changes still a black navbar. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the background color for the navbar is actually set on the `.container` within `.navbar-inner`.  Try this:

```
//navbar
$navbar-inverse-bg: #6dbcdb;
$navbar-inverse-border: #6dbcdb;

// Inverse navbar

.navbar-inverse .container {
background-color: $navbar-inverse-bg;
border-color: $navbar-inverse-border;
}
```

Comment: Well I still have to wait 8 minutes before I accept your answer. Thank you I'm now going to search for .container in the source files to learn more. thanks again!